# PHP Ajax 404 Not Found error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm newer to web development and I'm working on a small project for myself and some friends as a hobby. I've not touched PHP before this so I'm well aware that what you're about to see is garbage. The problem is that I don't even know if my code is good because I can't get it to run on my site.

Here's my javascript/ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/some.php",
    data : {
    json : JSON.stringify(data)
    }
});
```

And here's my some.php file:

```
<?php
$myFile = "json/your_array.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("impossible to open file");
$stringData = $_POST['data'];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Again, I'm well aware that what you're looking at is garbage, but I just need it to read the php file in the first place. I made a post for help with the code itself once before but I didn't get much help there.

The error I get in the web console just says 404 not found. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is your `some.php` in the top-most folder of your website? Preceding a relative url with a `/` means to search in the *root* directory for it. If both of these files are in the same place, you want `some.php`, **not** `/some.php`.

Comment: `"/some.php"` and `"some.php"` are two different things. `"/some.php"` specifies file location with respect to the root directory, whereas `"some.php"` specifies the file location with respect to the current directory. May be you want the later one.

Comment: Your Ajax URL path is not correct. Please make sure that you have correctly place it.

Comment: I've actually tried both "/some" and "some", neither work. And yes, the php file is in the same folder as my html document.

Comment: @BenL Which file is the 404 citing?

Comment: @Santi Well, it looks like it can't read the some.php file. In the console under the "Network" tab it says "404" under status, "POST" under Method, and "some.php" under File. The odd part is that I never had issues until I installed and ran the server through node.js, though the php file was still broken and wouldn't work...